# how to implement weather API

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

Hi i want to implement weather feature in one of my app.
so for this i need to use weather API.so can anyone suggest me which  weather API  and also tutorial how to implement this using jquery Mobile.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363052/best-weather-apis-free-for-commercial-use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few solutions here, it all depends how far are you willing to go. Do you want to immediately show final result or do you want to parse it by yourself?

## Complete solutions

**[Yahoo! Weather Feed Plugin for jQuery](http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zweatherfeed/)**

**HTML :**

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>
            First Page
        </h3>
        <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="test"></div>
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#test').weatherfeed(['UKXX0085','EGXX0011','UKXX0061','CAXX0518','CHXX0049']);
    });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/7qvJH/

**[Simple weather plugin](http://monkeecreate.github.com/jquery.simpleWeather/)**

Probably the best one, because you will get workable plugin but you can use it to show data how ever you want, where ever you want.

Working example (Not mine): http://jsfiddle.net/fleeting/a4hbL/

**HTML :**

```
<!-- Docs at http://simpleweather.monkeecreate.com -->
<div id="weather"></div>
```

**Javascript :**

```
// Docs at http://simpleweather.monkeecreate.com
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.simpleWeather({
    zipcode: '',
    woeid: '2357536',
    location: '',
    unit: 'f',
    success: function(weather) {
      html = '<h2>'+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
      html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
      html += '<li class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</li>';
      html += '<li>'+weather.tempAlt+'&deg;C</li></ul>';

      $("#weather").html(html);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
    }
  });
});
```

## Tutorials

**[Tutorial 1](http://papermashup.com/using-googles-weather-api/)**

**Source :** Google weather feed

This is a simple tutorial. There you will find everything to do it by yourself. Just be warned, it requires PHP and jQuery.

**[Tutorial 2](http://tutorialzine.com/2012/05/weather-forecast-geolocation-jquery/)**

**Source :** Yahoo weather feed

Another great tutorial. It requires only jQuery. There you will find everything you need to do to make it work.

**Demo :** http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2012/05/weather-forecast-geolocation-jquery/

While this tutorial have some flaws (it requires your Geo location) it can be used to manually create new weather plugin.

**Edit**
[The last tutorial got an update.](https://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/weather-web-app-geolocation-revisited) Now it uses OpenWeatherMap instead of Yahoo.

Comment: jsfiddle is deleted! and Yahoo! Weather Feed Plugin for jQuery is no longer supported